# Error: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) add gallery image in document pdf

Tags: java, android, image, pdf, kotlin

I have difficulty adding images from the mobile gallery in the pdf document I am creating. Passing the image path returns the following error: Error: Failed to open: ENOENT (this file or directory does not exist).
I created a class that the user can choose photos from gallery or capture a new image by camera. I am storing the path of these images in an arraylist. So I need to pass these paths to the function that creates the pdf document.

```
private val pathImage: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()

private fun openCam() {
    imageCapture.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                val diretorio: File =
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                val imagem =
                    File(diretorio.path + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpg")
                uri = Uri.fromFile(imagem)
                val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAM)
            } else {
                requestPermission()
            }
        }
    })

   private fun openGatelry() {
    imageGallery.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, R.string.select_picture.toString()), GALLERY)
        }
    })
}

 override fun onActivityResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    resultCode: Int,
    data: Intent?
) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == CAM && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val novaIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri)
        sendBroadcast(novaIntent)
        val imageCam = uri.getPath()
        if (imageCam != null) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Camera: "+imageCam)
            pathImage.add(imageCam)
        }
    } else if (requestCode == GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val clipData = data.clipData
        if (clipData != null) {
            for (i in 0 until clipData.itemCount) {
                val uri: Uri = clipData.getItemAt(i).uri
                pathImage.add(uri.path.toString())
                showImages()
            }
        } else {
            val uri = data.data
            if (uri != null) {
                pathImage.add(uri.path.toString())
                showImages()
            }
        }
    }
}


// Do something when user press the positive button
                val mDoc = Document()
                //pdf file name
                val mFileName = SimpleDateFormat(
                    "ddMMyyyy_HHmmss",
                    Locale.getDefault()
                ).format(System.currentTimeMillis())
                //pdf file path
                val mFilePath =
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + mFileName + ".pdf"
                try {
                    //create instance of PdfWriter class
                    PdfWriter.getInstance(mDoc, FileOutputStream(mFilePath))
                    //open the document for writing
                    mDoc.open()
                    val image = Image.getInstance("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1573066971461.jpg")
                    mDoc.add(image)
                    //close document
                    mDoc.close()
```

Comment: You are getting a `content` `Uri`, so `uri.path.toString()` is meaningless. Hold a list of `Uri` values, not a list of "paths".

Answer (score 1):

Before using the file make sure it is exists

```
// Make sure the directory exists.
File(mFilePath).mkdirs()
```

Also check whether image file exist or not before access it.

```
File imageFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1573066971461.jpg");
if(imageFile.exists())
```

Besides this don't forgot to take permissions from user

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: But the way to take the image of the internal storage of the phone is right?

Comment: Did you take the path using Image Picker or hard coded?

Comment: I used:  `val image = File(diretorio.path + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpg")` I not used Picker

Comment: This is not valid. Who create image in this path? You should use Image picker or something like that `File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");`

Comment: Understand. I will edit the question. In the other class I get images (gallery / camera). Alas how do I send to the generate pdf class and use these selected images in the document.

Comment: please help me, I'm trying to do this for a long time and I can't attach the images to the pdf document

Comment: Then take image path from `pathImage` and write to pdf

Comment: can you help me with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201972/discussion-between-md-asaduzzaman-and-tecnologia-da-net).